# laravel shows old CSRF tokens resulting in a tokenmismatchException

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, routes, csrf

I'm using **Laravel** for a project where I need the **CSRF token** for API calls.
My CSRF meta tag *sometimes* contains tokens that are expired. By refreshing it's good to go for like 10 new calls. So after like 10 refreshes I get the ***TokenMismatchException*** from my AJAX calls.  Making this API call an CSRF exception is not an option because the API call is heavy-loaded and contains valuable information.

I didn't customize any middelware classes.

My AJAX call in javascript looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/getAllProducts',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            type: "gpu",
            hash: md5hash,
            _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')

        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            md5hash = '';
            products = response;
            $('.more-information').fadeIn();
            $.getScript("/js/filter-products.js", function(){
                filterProducts();
            });

            $.getScript("/js/createPopup.js", function(){
                $('.more-information').on('click', createPopup);
                $('.open-details').on('click', createPopup);
            });
        }
    });
```

My route looks like this

```
route::post('/getAllProducts', 'PartsController@getAllProducts');
```

The meta csrf token is generated like the standard Laravel app.blade.php

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

I'm aware there are other questions about this issue but I didn't find a solution. I tried several of them.

Here is the list of solutions I tried:

- add jquery Ajaxsetup
- update laravel
- clear cache

Really hope someone can help me

Comment: Side note: If your `<script>` is in a `.blade.php` file, you could always use `var _token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";`, although it's still best to keep JS and PHP separate when at all possible. As to why you're getting old tokens; couldn't say.

Answer (score 0):

Set token in ajax setup.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried this before and doesn't work. It looks like Laravel refreshes the token after my page loaded. I don't think the mistake is in my javascript since it works 9/10 of the time.

Comment: May be session is timeout? This code validate csrf-token:
        **$sessionToken = $request->session()->token();**
        $token = $request->input('_token') ?: $request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN');
        if (! $token && $header = $request->header('X-XSRF-TOKEN')) {
            $token = $this->encrypter->decrypt($header);
        }

Comment: i tried changing the session lifetime from 120 to 86400. Still after like 8 calls with the same CSRF token suddenly changes AFTER loading the page. Maybe there is some option to prevent the CSRF token from changing in a session, you know how?

Comment: Hm, I didn't hear about it. If I found solution, I will write it.